# How to find the number of unique triplets summing to number K?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Coming from Stack Overflow forum because someone told me to ask here for rigorous proofs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60261555/three-sums-problem-space-complexity-why-is-it-on

For a given sequence of N distinct integers and a target sum K. 
For example:

$-8, -6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 12$

$K = 0$

We want to find out the number of unique triplets summing to the target sum.
In this example, the number of permutations will be 3:

$(-8, 2, 6), (-8, 3, 5), (-6, 1, 5)$

So from here, I can see the permutation is definitely less than ${N\choose 3}$, since all numbers are distinct.
How do I mathematically find the number of unique triplets summing to a given number?

Comment: None of the triplets you give sums to $3$.  Two of them sum to $0$ and one sums to $1$.  That is, $-8+2+6=0$, for example.  I don't understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: @saulspatz, Oh my deep apologies, fixed typo! All of them should add up to 0.

Comment: What are you asking?  There won't be a simple closed formula, if that's what you are hoping for.

Comment: @lulu, Oh there isn't one like n choose k? If that's the case can we find the asymptotic bound of the problem - to be more specific, to prove why the number of permutations is always bounded by O(n^2)? Let me add more information to the question.

Comment: It's clear that the answer will depend on the elements in the set, not just $N$ and $K$.  You can do a simple search:  for every pair of elements $(a,b)\in S$ we ask if $K-a-b\in S$.  That's why it is $O(N^2)$, since you just need to search over pairs.

Comment: I see, thank you! It made sense. if you write that as an answer I will accept it!